# Pattern matching using regex

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to match a pattern with line read from file, but the file contains varying random parts in each line after a certain point ? So how can I only match till part of line read ?

I've tried to match but the issue I face is that when the later half of line has random things I am unable to write common pattern to it

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\s+\w+\(\w+\)\,\s+')

pattern.search(' .CEVAXM6_NO_AXI4(CEVAXM6_NO_AXI4),  //This part is random')
```

The line read at times wont have anything after , sometimes has //description...
I want my code to compare the pattern only till the comma(`,`)

I am very confused on how to do it ?

Comment: It's unclear what data you are trying to capture here.  Are you looking to get `.CEVAXM6_NO_AXI4`?  Or perhaps ` .CEVAXM6_NO_AXI4(CEVAXM6_NO_AXI4)`?

Comment: I am trying to match the pattern till the comma(,) this same format repeats but has some random words sometimes after the , I just want to check the line and get the prevline actually @JPeroutek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question, you don't specify very clearly what the goal is, aside from "read the contents before the comma".  [Here is a link](https://regex101.com/r/cJRw7r/1/) to a very generic regex that seems to do what you want.  Reproduced below to prevent link-rot:

```
import re

regex = r"(.+),.*"

test_str = " .CEVAXM6_NO_AXI4(CEVAXM6_NO_AXI4),  //This part is random"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

I generated this code using regex101 (credit where it is due).

Essentially, I just defined a capture group that gets everything up until the first comma, and leaves off anything after it.  If this regex is insufficient, I suggest updating your question with more specifics and details.